# Drawing lines of constant latitude with cartopy on North Polar Stereo projection

Tags: python, cartopy

I'd like to draw two lines at 88 and 84 degrees north on a cartopy north polar stereo map, but am stumped as to how to do it.

I've tried with:

```
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, xlocs=[], ylocs=[88,84])
gl.n_steps = 90
```

and also:

```
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
```

and receive:

"Cannot label gridlines on a NorthPolarStereo plot.  Only PlateCarree and Mercator plots are currently supported."

but it seems like ax.gridlines just isn't set up for north polar stereo.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be available in the next release (0.18). You can test it out if you build/install CartoPy from git master.

Comment: Just got round to using this with cartopy 0.18 - thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon, seems like the update to cartopy 0.18 has introduced several other bugs for polar stereo plots

Comment: It would be good to report those over on the CartoPy issue tracker: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues